# Spark read only in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have setup a Spark cluster config with HDFS and I know that default file path will be read by Spark  all in HDFS example :

```
/ad-cpc/2014-11-28/ Spark will read in : hdfs://hmaster155:9000/ad-cpc/2014-11-28/
```

sometimes I wonder how can i force Spark read a file in local without reConfig my cluster ( to not use hdfs).

please help me !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local filesystem can be referred from Spark with the prefix **file:///**

```
Eg: sparkContext.textFile("file:///<<absolute path to file>>")
```

This command reads a file from local file system.

Note: If executed in multi node cluster then this file should be available on all nodes.

Comment: i tried the same thing, but still getting the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:` error. I tried `file:///home/user/file.dat`